# Как вернуть список при использовании lambda

Tags: python, map, lambda

Получается, если применяю list() при печати. Как сделать так, чтобы функция возвращала list?

```py
STR = 'Happy Birthday to you'
song = lambda x: map(lambda i: STR if i[0] != 2 else STR[:-6] + 'dear ' + i[1], enumerate([x, x, x, x]))
print(list(song('Iris')))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

как вариант:

```
STR = 'Happy Birthday to you'
song = lambda x: [*map(lambda i: STR if i[0] != 2 else STR[:-6] + 'dear ' + i[1], enumerate([x, x, x, x]))]

print(song('Iris'))
```

вот так чуть покороче будет:

```
STR = 'Happy Birthday to you'
song = lambda x: [*map(lambda i: STR if i != 2 else f"{STR[:-7]} dear {x}", range(4))]

print(song('Iris'))
```

немного более хитрый вариант, чтобы ничего в строке не отрезать:

```
STR = 'Happy Birthday %'
song = lambda x: [*map(lambda i: STR.replace("%", "to you" if i != 2 else f"dear {x}"), range(4))]

print(song('Iris'))
```

и покороче вариант

```
STR = 'Happy Birthday '
song = lambda x: [*map(lambda i: STR + ("to you" if i != 2 else f"dear {x}"), range(4))]

print(song('Iris'))
```

Еще немного компактности - экономим на `if`:

```
song = lambda x: [*map(lambda i: STR if i else f"{STR[:-7]} dear {x}", range(-2, 2))]

song = lambda x: [*map(lambda i: STR.replace("%", "to you" if i else f"dear {x}"), range(-2, 2))]

song = lambda x: [*map(lambda i: STR + ("to you" if i else f"dear {x}"), range(-2, 2))]
```

Чуть другой подход без `if` вообще и **пока самый компактный вариант** :) :

```
STR = 'Happy Birthday '
song = lambda x: [STR + [f'dear {x}', 'to you'][bool(i)] for i in range(-2,2)]
```

И **новый рекордсмен** по длине кода:

```
STR = 'Happy Birthday '
song = lambda x: [STR + [f'dear {x}', 'to you'][int(i)] for i in "1101"]
```

Comment: Вариант с `range` хороший :)

Comment: @gil9red, в итоге получил самый короткий вариант, без `if` и явных проверок, но конечно выглядит жутким извратом :)

Answer (score 1):

```
STR = 'Happy Birthday to you'
song = lambda x: list(map(lambda i: STR if i[0] != 2 else STR[:-6] + 'dear ' + i[1], enumerate([x, x, x, x])))
print(song('Iris'))
```